# A Sine of Greatness

Tags: code-golf, math, trigonometry

## Introduction

Everyone's heard of [sine (sin)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine), [cosine (cos)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Sine.2C_cosine_and_tangent), [tangent (tan)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Sine.2C_cosine_and_tangent), [cotangent (cot)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Right-angled_triangle_definitions), [secant (sec)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Secant), and [cosecant (csc)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Right-angled_triangle_definitions). Nearly every angle  has them.

Far less known, or remembered, are the [exsecant (exsec)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exsecant), [excosecant (excsc)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exsecant), [versine (versin)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versine#Definitions), and [coversine (cvs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versine#Definitions). Nearly every angle has those as well. There are some that are *even less* known, but we'll just stick to these.

I've created a visualization of these for angle θ, which is 45°.

[image]

---

## The Challenge

Create a program that takes an input of an angle `n`, in degrees, and will output:

1. the sine of angle `n`
2. the cosine of angle `n`
3. the tangent of angle `n`
4. the secant of angle `n`
5. *at least* one of the following. Every additional item from this list will earn a bonus -5%, for a maximum of -25%.

   - exsecant of angle `n`
   - cosecant of angle `n`
   - excosecant of angle `n`
   - versine of angle `n`
   - coversine of angle `n`
   - cotangent of angle `n`

If your score is a decimal after applying a bonus, round up to the nearest whole number.

---

## Input

You may accept your input through STDIN or through a function call. A single argument, `n`, will be passed.

`n` will always be a whole integer that is greater than 0, but less than or equal to 90.

---

## Output

Here is an example of the output for sine of 45°. All output items must be in this format. The order of the items does not matter.

```
sine: 0.70710678118
```

All items must have exactly 4 numbers after the decimal (precision to the ten-thousandths). Below are a few examples of rounding.

```
0 -> 0.0000
1 -> 1.0000
0.2588190451 -> 0.2588
5.67128181962 -> 5.6713
10 -> 10.0000
12.4661204396 -> 12.4661
```

Any nonexistent/undefined results should default to 0.

---

## Example

```
myprogram(60)

sine: 0.8660
cosine: 0.5000
tangent: 1.7321
secant: 2.0000
exsecant: 1.0000
cosecant: 1.1547
excosecant: 0.1547
versine: 0.5000
coversine: 0.1340
cotangent: 0.5774
```

---

## Scoreboard

For your score to appear on the board, it should be in this format:

```
# Language, Score
```

Or if you earned a bonus:

```
# Language, Score (Bytes - Bonus%)
```

Strikethroughs shouldn't cause a problem.

```js
function getURL(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function getAnswers(){$.ajax({url:getURL(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),useData(answers)}})}function getOwnerName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function useData(e){var s=[];e.forEach(function(e){var a=e.body.replace(/<s>.*<\/s>/,"").replace(/<strike>.*<\/strike>/,"");console.log(a),VALID_HEAD.test(a)&&s.push({user:getOwnerName(e),language:a.match(VALID_HEAD)[1],score:+a.match(VALID_HEAD)[2],link:e.share_link})}),s.sort(function(e,s){var a=e.score,r=s.score;return a-r}),s.forEach(function(e,s){var a=$("#score-template").html();a=a.replace("{{RANK}}",s+1+"").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SCORE}}",e.score),a=$(a),$("#scores").append(a)})}var QUESTION_ID=58283,ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",answers=[],answer_ids,answers_hash,answer_page=1;getAnswers();var VALID_HEAD=/<h\d>([^\n,]*)[, ]*(\d+).*<\/h\d>/;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:10px 0 0 30px}#scores-cont{padding:10px;width:600px}#scores tr td:first-of-type{padding-left:0}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"><div id="scores-cont"><h2>Scores</h2><table class="score-table"><thead> <tr><td></td><td>User</td><td>Language</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="scores"></tbody></table></div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="score-template"><tr><td>{{RANK}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SCORE}}</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Does the order of the output matter?

Comment: Pedantry ahead: "Every angle has them" - not true; odd multiples of 90 degrees don't have a tangent, for example. (It seems extremely bizarre to me that you require nonexisting values to give an output of zero. Would you really use a program that deliberately gave such misleading answers?) Also, I'd be interested to know why you regard the cosecant and cotangent as being more obscure than the secant; in my A-level maths classes we learned about those three at the same time.

Comment: Is capitalization fixed lowercase? I'd like output 'Sine, Cosine ...'

Comment: Hard to understand *Full program* vs  *input through a function call*

Comment: Is the angle input really `greater than 0`, so 0 is not allowed?

Comment: I am probably misreading, but I need some clarifications. As you say `a program than can output ...`, that means that I may or may not print those items. All I need to print is one of the `at least` at point 5. If I'm wrong, please clarify...

Comment: I've modified the question. To answer your question, you must output sine, cosine, tangent, secant, and at least one item from the list at #5. Every additional item from the list at #5 constitutes a bonus -5%. @edc65

Comment: I'm assuming builtins are allowed?

Comment: Yes they are. @ASCIIThenANSI

Comment: It looks like there are a lot of answers who do not convert to radians (input is supposed to be in degrees, right?) or handle the 90° case as prescribed (I cannot say I agree with returning 0, but still).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## CJam, <s>94</s> <s>89</s> <s>85</s> <s>81</s> 80 bytes

```
"sine tangent secant"S/{"co"1$+}%rd90/_i33Yb@[P*2/__ms\mc@mt]_Wf#W%+?.{d": %.4f"e%N}
```

The code is 84 bytes long and qualifies for a 5% bonus (*cotangent* and *cosecant*).

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22sine%20tangent%20secant%22S%2F%7B%22co%221%24%2B%7D%25rd90%2F_i33Yb%40%5BP*2%2F__ms%5Cmc%40mt%5D_Wf%23W%25%2B%3F.%7Bd%22%3A%20%25.4f%22e%25N%7D&input=60).

#### How it works

```
"sine tangent secant" e# Push that string.
S/                    e# Split it at spaces.
{"co"1$+}%            e# For each chunk, append a copy to the string "co", pushing
                      e# ["sine" "cosine" "tangent" "cotangent" "secant" "cosecant"].
rd90/                 e# Read a Double from STDIN and divide it by 90.
_i                    e# Push a copy and cast it to integer.
33Yb                  e# Push 33 in base 2, i.e., [1 0 0 0 0 1].
@                     e# Rotate the Double on top of the stack.
[                     e#
  P*2/                e# Multiply by Pi and divide by 2.
  __                  e# Push two copies of the result.
  ms                  e# Compute the sine of the topmost copy.
  \mc                 e# Swap and compute the cosine of the next copy.
  @mt                 e# Rotate and compute the tangent of the original.
 ]                    e#
 _Wf#                 e# Copy the array and raise all Doubles to the power -1.
                      e# This computes cosecant, secant and cotangent.
 W%                   e# Reverse their order.
 +                    e# Append to the original array.
 ?                    e# Select 33Yb if the integer part of the input divided by 90 is
                      e# (i.e., if the input is 90), the constructed array otherwise.
 .{                   e# For each function name and result:
   d                  e# Cast to Double (needed for 33Yb).
   ": %.4f"           e# Push a format string containing ": " and a 4-decimal float.
   e%                 e# Apply the formatting to the Double on the stack.
   N                  e# Push a linefeed.
 }                    e#
```

Answer (score 6):

## Julia, 162 - 10% = 144 bytes

```julia
n->for z=zip(split("sine cosine tangent secant exsecant cosecant cotangent"),[sind,cosd,tand,secd,i->secd(i)-1,cscd,cotd]) @printf("%s: %.4f\n",z[1],z[2](n))end
```

Ungolfed:

```julia
function f(n)
    # Construct a vector of names
    s = split("sine cosine tangent secant exsecant cosecant cotangent")

    # Construct a vector of functions
    o = [sind, cosd, tand, secd, i -> secd(i) - 1, cscd, cotd]

    # Print each in a loop
    for z = zip(s, o)
        @printf("%s: %.4f\n", z[1], z[2](n))
    end
end
```

Comment: Is it me or your "Unfolded" version has an additional loop?

Comment: You'd be better off without exsecant and cotangent.

Comment: @DavidArenburg The longer version has the same number of loops, it's just written differently than the short version.

Comment: @ThomasKwa I know, but I'm not going to win anyway. :P

Answer (score 5):

### Mathematica (Invalid at the moment), <s>134</s> <s>121</s> 104

Just for fun, surely it can be golfed down a lot

```
f[n_]:=(a={Sin,Cos,Tan,Sec,Cot,Csc};TableForm[N[#@n,4]&/@a,TableHeadings->{ToString[#]<>":"&/@a,None}])
```

And it should have a 5% bonus (Cot and Csc), therefore amounting at 99 characters

Example output:

[image: Example Output]

Comment: Wouldn't you get a better score by adding more functions?

Comment: @proud haskeller, I can try, but probably I will lose more than gain characters

Comment: Does this write the names of the functions out in full, or use `0` for `sec(90)`?

Comment: @Thomas Kwa it shouldn't, I'll test it when I have a chance

Comment: I really doubt this show actual function names

Comment: @DavidArenburg see edit, this is what it outputs

Comment: So the output isn't correct. It should output the full names as per OPs question. I.e., `sine: `, `cosine: `, etc. Also, you aren't rounding to the fourth digit. All the numbers should have 4 digits after the dot. See example output [per one of the answer in this thread](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22sine%20tangent%20secant%22S%2F%7B%22co%221%24%2B%7D%25rd90%2F_i33Yb%40%5BP*2%2F__ms%5Cmc%40mt%5D_Wf%23W%25%2B%3F.%7Bd%22%3A%20%25.4f%22e%25N%7D&input=60)

Comment: @DavidArenburg fair enough, I'll add a version which does as soon as I can

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, 66 - 10% = 59.4 bytes

```
j+V+Jc"sine secant tangent")+L"co"Jsmm%": %.4f"^.t.td7k^_1k3,Q-90Q
```

Calculates the sine, secant and tangent. Then, the co- functions are simply calculated via the formula `coF(x) = F(90 - x)`.

Comment: Does this give 0 for undefined?

Comment: @ThomasKwa Don't think so.

Comment: Then it is currently invalid.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 173 (182 - 5%)

**Edit** revised after clarification, now the bonus is 5%

**Edit** realized that the angle can not be 0

```js
// TEST - redefine alert
alert=x=>O.innerHTML=x

r=(a=prompt(i=0))*(M=Math).PI/180,V=_=>[s=M.sin(r),c=M.cos(r),(f=a-90)&&s/c,c/s,f&&1/c,1/s][i++].toFixed(4);
alert(`sine
tangent
secant`.replace(/.+/g,h=>h+`: ${V()}
co${h}: ${V()}`))

/* More bonus, but too longer 
r=(a=prompt(i=0))*(M=Math).PI/180,V=_=>[s=M.sin(r),c=M.cos(r),1-c,1-s,(f=a-90)&&s/c,c/s,f&&1/c,1/s][i++].toFixed(4);
alert(`sine
versine
tangent
secant`.replace(/.+/g,h=>h+`: ${V()}
co${h}: ${V()}`))
*/
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript ES6, <s>154</s> 148 (198 - 25%)

```
(n=0)=>[S='sine',(O='co')+S,T='tangent',C='secant',X=O+C,O+T,V='ver'+S,O+V,'ex'+C,'ex'+X].map((q,i)=>q+': '+[s=Math.sin(n),c=Math.cos(n),t=s/c,e=1/c,o=1/s,1/t,1-c,1-s,e-1,o-1][i].toFixed(4)).join`
`
```

Ungolfed:

```
(n=0)=>          // function declaration, accepts number, defaults to 0
  [              // create array of trig function names
    S='sine',    // sine
    (O='co')+S,  // cosine
    T='tangent', // tangent
    C='secant',  // secant
    X=O+C,       // cosecant
    O+T,         // cotangent
    V='ver'+S,   // versine
    O+V,         // coversine
    'ex'+C,      // exsecant
    'ex'+X       // excosecant
  ].map((q,i)=>  // map over names
                 // append ": <value rounded to 4 decimals>" to function name:
    q+': '+[s=Math.sin(n),c=Math.cos(n),t=s/c,e=1/c,o=1/s,1/t,1-c,1-s,e-1,o-1][i].toFixed(4)
  ).join`        // add newline between each function
`
```

Comment: Could you add a comma after "Javascript ES6" in your title so your score will parse correctly?

Answer (score 3):

## R, <s>122</s> <s>136</s> 134 bytes

```
n=scan()*pi/180;write(paste0(c("sine","cosine","tangent","secant","versine"),sprintf(": %.4f",c(sin(n),r<-cos(n),tan(n),1/r,1-r))),"")
```

---

**Example usage**

```
> n=scan()*pi/180;write(paste0(c("sine","cosine","tangent","secant","versine"),sprintf(": %.4f",c(sin(n),r<-cos(n),tan(n),1/r,1-r))),"")
1: 60
2: 
Read 1 item
sine: 0.8660
cosine: 0.5000
tangent: 1.7321
secant: 2.0000
versine: 0.5000
```

Comment: `scan()/(180/pi)` -> `scan()*pi/180`?

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, 282 (375 - 25%)

Error handling turned out to be somewhat complicated by floating-point errors; namely, `cos(90)` came out to a very small number instead of zero.

It's never going to be the top answer, but I like to think it **might** be the [shortest valid all-functions answer in a non-golfy language that doesn't have the trig functions in the default namespace](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OverlyNarrowSuperlative). ;-)

```py
import math as m
def p(q,r):print(q+':','%.4f'%r)
def a(n):
 n=n*m.pi/180
 C,S=round(m.cos(n),8),m.sin(n)
 A=S,1,0,C,1,S,C,0,C,S,1,C,0,1,S,1,C,-1,1,S,C,1,1,S,1
 def t():
  nonlocal A;u,v,w,x,y,*A=A;z=-1 if w>0 else 1
  try:return z*u/v+w,z*x/y+w
  except:return 0,0
 def q(y,x=''):J,K=t();p(x+y,J);p(x+'co'+y,K)
 q('sine');q('tangent');s='secant';q(s);q(s,'ex');q('versine')
```

Sample output:

```
>>> a(60)
sine: 0.8660
cosine: 0.5000
tangent: 1.7321
cotangent: 0.5774
secant: 2.0000
cosecant: 1.1547
exsecant: 1.0000
excosecant: 0.1547
versine: 0.5000
coversine: 0.1340
```

Comment: wouldn't `'.4f'%(r)` be shorter?

Comment: @xebtl: Thanks. I tend to forget that %-formatting still exists!

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, <s>182</s> 177 (236 - 25%)

Run with `-n` (1 byte added to uncorrected score).

```
$b=$_==90;$_/=57.296;$c=cos;$s=sin;sub f{printf"%s: %.4f\n",@_}$T=tangent;f$T,$b?0:$s/$c;f co.$T,$c/$s;$S=sine;f $S,$s;f co.$S,$c;$C=secant;f$C,$b?0:1/$c;f co.$C,1/$s;f ex.$C,$b?0:1-1/$c;f exco.$C,1/$s-1;$V=ver.$S;f$V,1-$c;f co.$V,1-$s
```

Nothing fancy.  It takes advantage of `-n` for implicit input, `$_` as a default argument to `sin` and `cos`, and barewords for strings.  The “undefined = 0” rule is hardcoded in using the ternary operator `?:` (it applies only for 90°).

One thing I learend is that apparently, you cannot have (or cannot *call*) a subroutine named `s` (or `m`, `y`, `tr`): `sub s {print 1}; s` yields `Substitution pattern not terminated at -e line 1`.

Comment: For some reason, your score is parsed even weirder.

Comment: Could you add a comma after "Perl" so your score is parsed correctly?

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, 165 (193 - 15%)

I am submit this a s a new answer because the idea is quite different from the [other](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58397/34438) one.  Please let me know if it is more appropriate to replace my first attempt.

```
$p=atan2 1,0;$b=$_-90;%h=qw(sine $s tangent $b?$s/$c:0 secant $b?1/$c:0 versine 1-$c);$_/=90/$p;sub e{$c=cos;$s=sin}e;sub f{eval"printf'$x$_: %.4f
',$h{$_}"for keys%h}f;$b=1;$_=$p-$_;e;$x=co;f
```

Run with `-n` (1 byte added).

Ungolfed:

```
# π/2
$p=atan2 1,0;

# trouble?
$b=$_-90;

# Construct a hash whose keys are the “base” function names,
# and whose values are the corresponding expressions in terms of sin and cos
%h=qw(sine $s tangent $b?$s/$c:0 secant $b?1/$c:0 versine 1-$c);

# Thanks to ‘-n’, input is in $_; convert to radians
$_/=90/$p;

# Compute sin and cos in a reusable way
sub e{$c=cos;$s=sin}
e;

sub f {
   eval "printf '$x$_: %.4f
', $h{$_}" 
      for keys %h
}

f;

# Now the “co” functions
# No trouble here
$b=1;

# x ← π/2 - x
$_=$p-$_;

e;
$x=co;
f
```

Since it does the four “co”-functions, I think it qualifies for a 3*5% = 15% bonus.

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, <s>100</s> <s>95</s> 94 bytes

Whoa, lotta perl answers.

```
$_=<>;printf"sine: %.4f\ncosine: %.4f\ntangent: %.4f\nsecant: %.4f\n",sin,cos,(sin)/cos,1/cos
```

Comment: Yeah, and you are doing pretty well with this straightforward approach :-).  You can shave off some bytes by using `-n` (counts for 1 byte) instead of `$_=<>`.  However, you have to convert from degrees to radians, and you do not handle the 90° case as prescribed. (With the latter, it seems like you are hardly alone among the answers here.)

Comment: Also, remember that the ancestor of Code Golf was Perl Golf :-)

Comment: I'm a little confused here... this uses radians. Was I supposed to use degrees?

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 159 = 186 - 15% bytes

```
s x=zipWith(\a b->a++": "++show b)(concatMap(\n->[n,"co"++n])$words"sine tangent versine secant")$map($(x*pi/180))[sin,cos,t,(1/).t,(1-).cos,(1-).sin,e.t,e.(1/).t]
e=sqrt.(+1).(^2)
t=tan
```

No ex-thingies to keep my clever naming scheme and since I didn't know how to shorten `(\x->x-1)`. `(-1)` is just a number.

Please complain if you want me to prettify (`mapM_ putStrLn`) the lines.

Comment: Thanks! Same for Alex A. and @orlp. The latter should maybe round up the net score.